# Antlr4 - ANTLR ERROR missing SEMI at '┐grammar' and could not find source file (CSC compilant)

Tags: parsing, visual-studio-2012, antlr

I have an project in .NET target using ANTLR and when I add new project using ANTLR it does not generate parser, old projects works ok.

```
grammar MyGrammar;

/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

Errors:

Error6  missing SEMI at '┐grammar'  C:\\... 1   3   MyGrammarLib
Error7  missing COLON at 'MyGrammar' while matching a rule  C:\\... 1   12  MyGrammarLib
Error5  '╗' came as a complete surprise to me   C:\\... 1   2   MyGrammarLib
Error4  '´' came as a complete surprise to me   C:\\... 1    1  MyGrammarLib
```

When I restart and rebuild it cannot generate CSC for all libs using ANTLR, It looks like my Visual Studio 2012 does not support Antlr Language and runtime tool anymore. **Also reinstalling ANTLR does not help. 
What happens?**

PK

Comment: The error message pretty much looks like you have a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in your files, and the default encoding is not UTF-8. Presumably "new projects" store files as UTF-8 with BOM, while "old projects" use a different file encoding. If that causes the problem, it should vanish when specifying `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` in the Java command line.

Comment: I have changed it to UTF-8, because I have diacritics it Debug path and it says it cannot find LÖA instead of LŠA. The file exists, property Full Path of g4 file contains LŠA, I also change the property tools -> options -> General -> Project Location after moving the project, but it did not help.

Comment: oh no, it is not caused by environmental options, I have to set the project directory, but it has relative path in its properties, so how do I change the encoding of relative paths? Other .cs files are all right, but g4 files cannot be custom bulit: Source file: "C:\Users\...\LÖA\trunk\projectName\CoMaTion\obj\Debug\CoMaTionalParser.cs" could not be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that ANTLR (or in fact the Java runtime environment) knows about the encoding of your files.

If it is UTF-8 (with or without [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)), this can be accomplished by specyfing it in the Java command line, e.g.

`java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar antlr-4.5-complete.jar`...

Comment: Maybe it works for Java target, I have no jar file in project folder, it can be equivalent to ANTLR4.Runtime.net45.dll. I forgot add tag Visual Studio. I will improve the question. The only way how to avoid it in Visual Studio is to clear all diacritics.

Comment: After removing diacritics it worked. Because of new release of .NET, I also had to change target Framework in **new** classLibs' properties to 4.5 (it was 4.5.2), but it is different chapter... [ANTLR cannot generate ‘org.antlr.v4.codegen.CSharp_v4_5_1Target’] (https://mhusseini.wordpress.com/2014/02/16/antlr-cannot-generate-org-antlr-v4-codegen-csharp_v4_5_1target-code-as-of-version-4-1-snapshot/)